# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, include

I think I did all the necessary configuration but I am still getting this:

```
Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory    File:c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2008\libs\boost_1_43_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp Line:17
```

Here are screenshots of setting I have done to add directories for include and lib files :

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't see the boost include and/or library directories in your configuration. Check again maybe?

Comment: The first 3 lines are for boost

Comment: One suggestion that will help in the future, is to define where the boost library is in an environment variable (we use BOOSTDIR).  Rather than entering the full path name.  This allows each developer/build box to put the boost lib's where it makes sense for them.  Also, it makes upgrading versions of boost trival as there are no changes to program.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally found the answer :) and I will write it here to help.

**Project>"YOURPROJECT" Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories** then select where you downloaded your library . This worked and all the above didn't, so make sure not to forget it .

Comment: HI Ahmed, Even after doing this, I get the same errors. Can u tell me which folder I need to exactly point to?

Comment: The folder that contains the library files .

Comment: (C++ newbie here). What exactly are the library files? I downloaded only the boost source files. Can I reference them in my own C++ project or do I need to compile boost first or get the boost binaries somewhere?

Comment: To check which version you are compiling with: Project >  Properties > Top right click on the pushButton Configuration Manager... > On the Active solution platform select x64 instead of x32 to compile it with x64.

Comment: In VS 2022: right click on your project in Solution Explorer > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories.

Comment: It also fixed the following issue for me: "Cannot open include file: 'boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp': No such file or directory"

Comment: I have to log in to upvote this solution.

Answer (score 10):

I installed boost from [the installer](http://www.boostpro.com/download/). It installs the library in c:\program files\boost.

Add the directory to your project's properties like the below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you need to add the path of "boost" directory in both 64bit and 32bit configurations. While adding the path, make sure to select appropriate platform (64bit or 32bit) depending upon your need. If you compile in both versions, you need add both.

Boost library directory is valid for both the above configurations.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was building targeting the win32 platform. Changing to x64 worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem... I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.6.3.  I think it got stuck somehow.  I had upgraded a solution with multiple projects from 2015 to 2019.  Most of the projects were building but for some reason one static library (outputting a .lib) kept complaining about some header files.

After several hours, I finally got Visual Studio C++ "unstuck" by disabling:
"Project Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories->dropdown->Edit ...->Checkbox Inherit from parent or project defaults"
This seems to have triggered some kind of rebuild of a cache of valid header files or something.  Now the compiler error has disappeared.  I went back into the same dialog and re-enabled "Inherit from parent or project defaults" and things are fine.

Answer (score 0):

mmake sure you are not looking at boost-system instead of boost-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install Turbodbc in a python environment and seeing errors similar to the one mentioned in this question, I have written a detailed answer for this in a different thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850615/5333178

Answer (score -1):

Add the namespace after all headers:

```
using namespace std;
```

removing from the header (.h) did the trick.

remove all the ".h" from all headers. Should work.