# Turbodbc installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, turbodbc

I tried installing `turbodbc` and it gives me the following error and not sure what's wrong here.

My python version is `3.7`

My command line output from Windows 10 Pro.

`C:\Users\marunachalam\Downloads>pip install turbodbc`

```
 Collecting turbodbc
      Using cached turbodbc-3.3.0.tar.gz (78 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2.0 in c:\users\marunachalam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from turbodbc) (2.4.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\marunachalam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from turbodbc) (1.13.0)
    Building wheels for collected packages: turbodbc
      Building wheel for turbodbc (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\marunachalam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MARUNA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-akbat0nu\\turbodbc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MARUNA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-akbat0nu\\turbodbc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MARUNA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qdxgecq5'
           cwd: C:\Users\MARUNA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-akbat0nu\turbodbc\
      Complete output (27 lines):
      warning: BOOST_ROOT enviroment variable not set
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\api_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\connect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\connection.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\constructors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\data_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\options.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      copying turbodbc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\turbodbc
      running egg_info
      writing turbodbc.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to turbodbc.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to turbodbc.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to turbodbc.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'turbodbc_intern' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for turbodbc
      Running setup.py clean for turbodbc
    Failed to build turbodbc
```

Comment: Like the error message says: 'Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/'

Comment: I already have that installed in my machine. I have Miscrosoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) and (x86) in my machine already.

Comment: Those are C++ *runtime* components. turbodbc requires that you build it from source, which requires a C++ *compiler*. [This page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has a lot of pre-compiled components for Python, but unfortunately turbodbc isn't one of them.

Comment: I tried my best but I could not get it through. I really liked to implement using turbodbc though but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer : Turbodc installation has problems with python version 3.8+. You will be able to install Turbodc on python 3.8+, but you'll face another error while using it (https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/258). So if you want to use Turbodbc, better to stick to python version 3.7 and below. Now lets get Turbodbc installed on your machine

This is going to be a long one. Stay with me -

1. As the error states, firstly you need 'Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools'. You'll get it on this page: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Scroll down to 'Build Tools for Visual Studio'. Download it.
2. Run the installer. Select 'C++ build tools' to install. Make sure to choose 'Windows 10 (or whatever version you prefer) SDK' as well to prevent this error later - https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/586
3. After installing build tools if you try to install Turbodbc (pip install turbodbc), you'll see another error - python fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/locale.hpp'. Which is to say the battle is half won. To resolve this error follow the steps listed here - https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/236. For your ease, I'll copy them below -
4. Download boost from https://www.boost.org/ (click on the "Current Release" version link, in my case "Version 1.72.0", then download the Windows zip file).
5. Unzip the zipfile somewhere on your PC.
6. In a command prompt, navigate to the boost top-level directory.
7. Run .\bootstrap.bat (this generates the b2 executable)
8. Run .\b2 (this generates the stage directory and contents, takes a few minutes to run)
9. Set the BOOST_ROOT env variable with something like
   set BOOST_ROOT=C:\your\path\to\boost\boost_1_72_0\boost_1_72_0
10. Run pip install turbodbc

That's all. Turbodbc should now be installed in your machine.

Comment: Steps 6, 7, and 8 are not needed if you want to install turbodbc. I just did it without it on Windows 10/Python 3.11 and it's working. "Most Boost libraries are header-only: they consist entirely of header files containing templates and inline functions, and require no separately-compiled library binaries or special treatment when linking". Source: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try follow

Sat, Jan 2 at 9:16 PM

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html.  got working on windows 10 using Python39, download/install MS Visual Studio 2019 Community, unzip boost, set BOOST_ROOT env variable, rerun pip install turbodbc

Comment: Please put proper instructions here and then reference